# Can voice overlap occur in different phrases?

Tags: voice-leading, satb

Is it possible for voices in one phrase to overlap with voices in another in SATB chorale style?

For example: the alto sings middle C in one phrase and in the next phrase the tenor sings D. This would be overlapping if it is in the same phrase, but would it still be voice overlapping if it is in different phrases?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and it happens (In Fugues it happens a lot).

But it is no not just possible in subsequent phrases, but also in chords, e.g. the tenor has a higher note then the alto in one chord.

Sometimes this is due to rules in choral writing (e.g no parallel 5th), sometimes it is because of sound-reasons.